How to maximize wezterm on startup?
Originally closed here https://github.com/wez/wezterm/issues/284
I could not get any of the solutions in the thread or the docs to work correctly in conjunction with
config.window_decorations = "NONE"


local mux = wezterm.mux
wezterm.on("gui-startup", function(cmd)
    local tab, pane, window = mux.spawn_window(cmd or {})
    window:gui_window():maximize()
end)

Maybe you can try this.

On a 13 inch macbook pro what I ended up doing is simply hard coding the initial rows/cols
config.initial_rows = 100
config.initial_cols = 205
config.window_decorations = "NONE"

This got me the perfect result.
